How do I find the angle of an ellipse in Python using image analysis?

I am trying to find the angle of the semi major axis of an ellipse with x axis. For this, I will have to find the major axis of an ellipse, get the equation of the major axis and then just arc tan of the gradient.
The approach I used in python is:
I first load the image and convert it to grayscale. Then, I binarize the grayscale image using a threshold (pixels above the threshold become white, and pixels below become black). Then iterate through each pixel in the binarized image. If a pixel is black (value 0), I calculate the Euclidean distance between that pixel and the center of mass (centroid) of the ellipse. The max distance will be the major axis and the coordinate of the pixel and the centre will be the two coordinates I can work with to get an equation of the major axis and theta. The problem is that I made a picture in powerpoint, rotated it to approximately 25 degrees but the answer I am getting is around 30 degrees so I dont know where I am going wrong. Can someone please help me.
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def euclidean_distance(a, row, col):
    """
    Calculates the Euclidean distance between two points.
    Args:
        a (tuple): Center of mass (x, y).
        row (int): Row index of the pixel.
        col (int): Column index of the pixel.
    Returns:
        float: Euclidean distance.
    """
    return np.sqrt((a[0] - col) ** 2 + (a[1] - row) ** 2)

def angle(a, row, col):
    """
    Calculates the angle between the major axis and the x-axis.
    Args:
        a (tuple): Center of mass (x, y).
        row (int): Row index of the pixel.
        col (int): Column index of the pixel.
    Returns:
        float: Angle in degrees.
    """
    slope = (a[0] - col) / (a[1] - row)
    return math.atan(slope)

# Load the image
image_path = "/Users/yahya2/Desktop/xy1.png"
img = cv2.imread(image_path)
a = ndimage.center_of_mass(img)

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Binarize the grayscale image
_, img_bin = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Get the dimensions of the image
rows, cols = img_bin.shape
max_length = 0
max_row, max_col = 0, 0

# Loop through each pixel in the image
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        # Check if the pixel is black (0)
        if img_bin[row, col] == 0:
            length = euclidean_distance(a, row, col)
            if length > max_length:
                max_length = length
                max_row, max_col = row, col

# Calculate the angle
major_axis_angle = angle(a, max_row, max_col)
print(f"Major axis angle (degrees): {major_axis_angle:.2f}")

# Visualize the result
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.scatter(max_col, max_row, color='red', marker='x', s=100)
plt.show()

This is the result I am getting:


I think you are on the right path!!! If i were you, when i was learning i usally plotted every single part of the process. With that being said i would try to plot the center, the small and bigger radious, and the ellipse that was created. Also, opencv can do this for you automatically.

Do a preliminary debugging and post a [mre] including a sample image. Anyway, you said you created a sample image rotated approximately 25 degree. Then what's the problem with -0.50 radian = -28.6 degree?

Binarizing the image is causing data loss, which in turn leads to incorrect determination of the max-(row, col) points of the major axis. Essentially, this results in calculating the angle of an almost-major axis.

You might want to use a least-squares fitting approach, after extracting the ellipse boundary coordinates. You could follow for example this answer. What it calculates are the coefficients of the ellipse (called w in the answer). From the coefficients, you can calculate the angle; here, you could follow for example Wikipedia (bottom of section In Cartesian coordinates → General ellipse)

Alternatively, you could also use the Hough transform, e.g. with the skimage package (see their ellipse detection example)

You just deleted a related question that had an answer. It is a pity that this user (destructioneer) spent time on your question and then you just delete it... Was there a solution?

Since I don't know python... I wonder if a = ndimage.center_of_mass(img) will give center of the ellipse.

OpenCV fitEllipse will tell you the angle.

see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78603983/are-there-some-other-methods-which-i-could-use-to-better-identify-all-the-cells and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78599551/how-do-i-filter-out-the-contours-i-do-not-want

You seem to be using an ellipse that is not oriented at 25deg. I tried inputting one from Desmos into your program and it gave me 24.6deg back (pretty accurate).
Although it won't be perfect (if you're expecting it to be) cause binarizing the image causes data loss, which in turn leads to incorrect determination of the max-(row, col) points of the major axis. Essentially, this results in calculating the angle of an almost-major axis.

Binarization doesn't necessarily hurt in a case like this. Whether quantization affects accuracy depends on the number of pixels, whether noise is present in the image, and so on.

There are a few approaches to this problem, depending on the accuracy and precision you want.
Are you familiar with OpenCV? Or any of the image processing libraries for Python?
To take OpenCV as the image processing library, you could run cv::findContours() on the image, get the edge points, and then fit a rotated rectangle to those image points. That rotated rectangle will give you the major and minor axes. I've used that technique, and it works just fine.
Here's the OpenCV documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d62/tutorial_bounding_rotated_ellipses.html
This might be of use:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/finding-minimum-enclosing-rectangle-in-opencv-python/
If you don't want to use OpenCV--a large library--then you could search for an implementation in Python of an algorithm to find the "minimum enclosing rectangle," a fairly standard algorithm in computational geometry.
Eberly is the go-to reference for theory and pseudocode, and he has a PDF for this case:
https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MinimumAreaRectangle.pdf
User spuckhafte mentioned a potential problem with binarization, meaning using whole pixels instead of just the "true" edge points. I suspect that binarization won't be a problem with your image, but you could also explore finding sub-pixel edge points.
Finding a sub-pixel edge requires interpolation of pixel values. In the neighborhood of a transition from background (white) to foreground (black), interpolation would use a curve fit (or similar technique) to determine the sub-pixel (x,y) position of the maximum gradient--the steepest slope of the curve fit.
I provided an explanation of sub-pixel edge finding here:
what is the relationship between image edges and gradient?
If your ellipse had rougher edges, or if you had a photo of a real-world elliptical shape, then I would suggest finding a Hough fit, or perhaps using one of the other ellipse-fitting algorithms. For your example, that may be overkill. It takes a while working with a large number of real-world images to learn the ins and outs of Hough fits, so I wouldn't recommend diving into that.
https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_circular_elliptical_hough_transform.html

Thankyou so much. I will work on your suggestions to improve it further!
